# What is a Presheaf (intuitively) and help with the technical machinery.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I have come across things such as that a Presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ associates data (such as rings, groups, other sets etc.) to open sets $U$ of $X$. That the Presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ becomes a Sheaf if each of these objects (rings, groups, etc.) are separated and can be glued together. That kind of makes sense.

How would one demonstrate a presheaf on, for example a Topological space

$(X,\mathcal{T})$ where $X = \{a,b,c\}$ and $\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset,X,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\{b,c\}\}$

The proper open sets in $X$ are $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\{b,c\}\}$ and there are inclusions $\{a\} \subset \{a,b\}$, $\{b\} \subset \{a,b\}$ and $\{b\} \subset \{b,c\}$ and furthermore we have a couple different open coverings for $X$ such as $\{\{a\} \cup \{b,c\}\}$ and $\{\{a,b\} \cup \{b,c\}\}$ ?

By definition; A presheaf of $\mathcal{F}$ of sets on $X$ consists of the data;

a) for every open subset $U \subseteq X$ a set $\mathcal{F}(U)$

b) for every inclusion $V \subseteq U$ of open subsets of $X$, a morphism of sets $\rho_{UV}:\mathcal{F}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(V)$,

with the conditions of $\mathcal{F}(\emptyset) = 0$, $\rho_{UU}$ is the identity map, and $\rho_{UW} = \rho_{VW} \circ \rho_{UV}$

What can we say that $\mathcal{F}(U)$ are according to the Topological space given above? - What does $\mathcal{F}(U)$ look like? What could be possible sections and can they be glued to create a sheaf? I imagine that since we have an open covering $\{\{a,b\} \cup \{b,c\}\}$, can we just glue along $b$ to obtain $X$?

Lastly I wonder, the more intuitive part - I know that $\mathcal{F}$ is a functor, thus when this functor is applied to some open set we get a bunch of sections (morphisms)? But then if have $\rho_{UV}: \mathcal{F}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(V)$, then we are sending these sections/morphisms concerning some sort of structure (the Presheaf data $\mathcal{F}(U)$ on $U$) built out of $U$ on to the presheaf data built out of $V$ - but $V \subseteq U$! Is there no loss of information? I see this as saying $\mathcal{F}(\{a,b\}) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(\{a\})$ I of course want to understand what kind of "data" these presheaves are associating, but furthermore wonder if there would be a loss of information - and whats the point?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: One way you can always get a presheaf (in fact, a sheaf) on any topological space $X$ is to fix some topological space $Y$ and send any open subset $U$ of $X$ to the set of continuous functions from $U$ to $Y$ with the obvious restriction maps.

Comment: Thanks Tobias!.. Is what your saying the same as:  Showing the Presheaf $U \mapsto \mathrm{Hom}(U, Y)$ is a Sheaf?

Answer (score 5):

I dont know if this will be helpful to you but it is the intuition that I use to think about things. A sheaf is (intuitively) the set of function of some type, continuous, differentiable, analytic, algebraic etc.. So $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is all such function defined on the open set $U$. The maps $r_{UV}:\mathcal{F}(U)\rightarrow \mathcal{F}(V)$ are restriction, sending a function on $U$ to its restriction to the smaller set $V$. 
Viewed in this light all of the machinery of sheaf theory makes perfect sense. And this was the original motivation.

Comment: This is very helpful actually! Makes much more sense then the random symbol blowers that they use on the pages of many of the references I have looked at! - ok, so in this context, where does the pre-sheaf come in? a bunch of functions that are only continuous etc. locally but not globally?

Comment: If you look at the criteria for a presheaf to be a sheaf, they make alot of sense, a function is zero if all of its restrictions are zero, etc. I think presheafs are a kind of formal intermediate, most constructions try to turn them into sheaves. The whole theory is actually simple when viewed in the right light.